# Element height in Javascript is not render height in DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to get the absolute rendered height of an element in Google Chrome:

[image]

When I inspect the element, the height shows up as 38.4:

[image]

What's the deal, how can I get the real height value?

Comment: It's rounded to the nearest whole integer. See [MDN's documentation of clientHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientHeight).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried parsing it into float by using `parseFloat(elementHeight);` ?